# Can the Fock-Schwinger (radial) gauge condition be written as momentum space divergence?

Tags: gauge, canonical-conjugation

The Lorenz Gauge can be written (in QED) as $\partial^{\mu}A_{\mu} = 0$ or equivalently as $p^{\mu}A_{\mu} = 0$. The Fock-Schwinger gauge is similar: $x^{\mu}A_{\mu} = 0$.

Can it be written equivalently as $\frac{\partial}{\partial p^{\mu}}A^{\mu} = 0$, or is this naive?